# The Windows Process Activation Service could not be started. Error 2

Tags: iis, windows-10, was

After a windows update I am unable to start IIS.

> Cannot start service W3SVC on computer.

When trying to start this service from CMD I find that a dependency service or group failed to start. That being the WAS (Windows Process Activation Service).

When trying to start this in CMD I get the following error.

> The Windows Process Activation Service service could not be started.
>
> A system error has occurred.
>
> System error 2 has occurred.
>
> The system cannot find the file specified.

I have tried the following:

- Reinstalled IIS and Windows Process Activation Service, several times
- I verified that I do have a "C:\inetpub\temp\appPools" folder
- Removed all files in config files in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config and then clean re installed IIS to get the clean configs.
- Insured both WAS and W3SVC services are set to automatic and rebooted.
- Checked that HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP start is set to 3(automatic) and the is no “NoRun” key

Is there anything else to check?

Comment: [use Windows 10 DVD/ISO and repair Windows](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html)

Comment: What have you done to resolve this error? I am getting the same, and it is annoying

Answer (score 3):

If this problem still persists then below link could be referred.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/iis-wont-start-after-upgrade-to-1803-was-fails/0546e24f-6573-4445-b8d5-d17096a5fcfc

"we had the same issue very often on customer PC.
We now find a solution to get the WAS-Services started after upgrade 1803.
Just delete the registry entry "NanoSetup" with running cmd command.
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\WAS\Parameters" /v NanoSetup /f

Now you can start the service again."

Answer (score 0):

I rolled back the windows update and my IIS started working again.

I view this as a temporary solution as I am not satisfied with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

It just has a simple solution, you don't need to reinstall Windows or removing updates, It worked for me so sharing it with all of you,

1. if you already using IIS and have site's configurations and files in C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config and C:\inetpub\wwwroot, Back up all files from the folder C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config and C:\inetpub\wwwroot, if you are installing ISS for the first time then you don't need to have a back up.
2. On Taskbar right-click on Start button select 'Run', type appwiz.cpl hit Enter.Click on 'Turn Windows features on or off'.
3. Uncheck 'Internet Information Services' and 'Windows Process Activation Service' click OK button.
4. After restarting Windows, Delete 'inetpub' folder on C: drive.
5. Open 'Turn Windows features on or off window' again.
6. Check 'Internet Information Services' and 'Windows Process Activation Service' click OK button.
7. After restarting Windows open folder C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config.
8. Right click on the file named 'applicationHost' Select Open with Notepad.
9. In Notepad, Copy all the content of the file.
10. Select New in File Menu and Paste all the content in the new file.
11. Save this file in C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config with the name 'applicationHost.config.tmp', Don't forget choosing 'All Files' in the 'Save as type' box.
12. Otherwise, file will be saved as applicationHost.config.tmp.txt which will not work.
13. Type 'Services.msc' in Run, Find 'Windows Process Activation Service' in Services window.
14. Watch running the service successfully without any errors after clicking on start.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the Windows Process Activation Service was unchecked 
 I add IIS before I checked Process Activation Service

- go to : control panel >> turn windows feature on or off >> uncheck IIS
- control panel >> turn windows feature on or off >> check Windows Process Activation 
  Service
- then check IIS and you are ready to go.